# RMagick smart resizing

Tags: imagemagick, rmagick

Is there a way to make RMagick resize an image like this:

- Resize so that both width and height are smaller than, say, 200px, but keep aspect ratio
- If width > 200 and width > height, resize so that width = 200 and resize height accordingly
- If height > 200 and height > width, resize so that height = 200 and resize width accordingly

*EDIT*: By the way, I am looking for [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize) syntactic way of achieving this, and not API-based manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

this method should work, image is an Rmagick image, width and height are integers (max size of the image)

```
def resize_to_limit(image,width, height)
  geometry = Magick::Geometry.new(width, height, 0, 0, Magick::GreaterGeometry)
  image.change_geometry!(geometry) do |new_width, new_height, img|
    img.resize!(new_width, new_height)
  end
  image
end
```

ex. i want to resize an image to 2000 if its bigger than that, preserving the aspect ratio

```
image = resize_to_limit(image,2000,2000)
```